# Different site at HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https

I am taking over a multi-site Apache server, with two websites (A and B). Going to website A's url via http works fine. Going to the same url, but using https, shows website B. Why is this, and how do I make https://urlA.com go to website A?

Comment: Post the server config. This is likely related to how the server blocks are defined.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The servers were set up with VirtualHosts, but there was no VirtualHost for port 443. So it looked something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 99.9.9.999:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
ServerName example.com

    <Directory "/var/www/example">
            Options Indexes
            AllowOverride None
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Adding a VirtualHost listening on port 443, with the SSLCertFiles specified fixed the problem.

```
<VirtualHost 99.9.9.999:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
ServerName example.com

    <Directory "/var/www/example">
            Options Indexes
            AllowOverride None
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/_.example.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/gd_example.crt
SSLEngine on

</VirtualHost>
```